# Round wait time (to be allowed to award a bounty) up

Tags: bug, bounty, user-interface

I tried awarding a bounty within twenty-four hours after offering it, and was told "You may award your bounty in 2 hours.". In fact, though, more than 2 but less than 3 hours remained until I would be allowed to offer the bounty. Now, the site does this a lot, for example saying a chat event will start in *n* hours when in fact it will start in *n*+½. But in the case of "You may award your bounty in *n* hours", I think the rounding should always be upward (using the [ceiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiling_function)) rather than downward. After all, it's actually false to say that I'd be allowed to offer the bounty in (precisely) two hours, but true to say I'd be allowed to offer it in precisely three hours. (This is unlike the case of a chat event's starting in *n* hours, where rounding down is better so people don't miss the event.)

I'm tagging this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) rather than [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) because I think that the current behavior is counterintuitive and thus poor UI and should be fixed.